# Building executable with Android NDK

Tags: android, cmake

I am trying to build an executable using the Android NDK.  To do this, I've created an "Android Library" project and included all my native code (cpp) files in it under the directory "src/main/cpp".

In the CMakeLists.txt file, I've added the following.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set (TEST_SRC
    src/test/cpp/test.cpp
)

add_library (test-lib SHARED ${TEST_SRC})
add_executable(test-exec ${TEST_SRC})
```

When I perform a build, I see that the library is created correctly in my build output directory (libtest-lib.so), however, the executable is not produced.

I decided to build my project with command-line (./gradlew clean build --info --debug) and found the following log message.

```
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target test-exec because no 
targets are specified and library build output file extension isn't 
'so'.
```

It seems that the android NDK is purposefully disabling my executable from being built :( Is there a way around this? Or did I specify something incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Since I posted this answer, I have found a much cleaner solution. There is no need to modify anything in `Android.mk` files. The following is the relevant portion of `app/build.gradle` (The original gradle script belongs to the [syncopoli project](https://gitlab.com/fengshaun/syncopoli). You can find the original up-to-date version of this `build.gradle` script [here](https://gitlab.com/fengshaun/syncopoli/blob/master/app/build.gradle):

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        // ...

        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                // I only want the following targets to be built
                targets 'rsync', 'ssh'
            }
        }

        ndk {
            // add whatever ABIs you want here
            abiFilters 'armeabi'
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            // all my external sources are under src/main/jni
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
}

// this is the meat. It copies the binaries to appropriate location
// after externalNativeBuildRelease task is finished.
// you can change the paths to match where your binaries live and where
// you want them to go
gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { task ->
    if (task.name == "externalNativeBuildRelease") {
        def src = rootProject.file('app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj/local/')
        def dst = rootProject.file('app/src/main/assets/')

        copy {
            from(src) {
                // the objs directory has all the .o files I don't care about
                exclude "**/objs"
            }

            into dst

            // this is purely for debugging purposes. it might come in handy
            eachFile {
                println "file = " + it.getPath()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

my `src/main/jni/Android.mk` has the following content:

```
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

I have hit this issue and worked around it by creating extra tasks in gradle that call `ndk-build` manually and setting the project to depend on these tasks.

This is the relevant part of `app/build.gradle`:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    def ndkDirProperty = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')
    def ndkDirPrefix = ndkDirProperty != null ? ndkDirProperty + '/' : ''

    def ndkBuildExt = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? ".cmd" : ""

    commandLine "${ndkDirPrefix}ndk-build${ndkBuildExt}", '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath,
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}

// Cleanup task to remove previously generated binaries
task ndkClean(type: Exec) {
    def ndkDirProperty = properties.getProperty('ndk.dir')
    def ndkDirPrefix = ndkDirProperty != null ? ndkDirProperty + '/' : ''

    def ndkBuildExt = Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS) ? ".cmd" : ""

    commandLine "${ndkDirPrefix}ndk-build${ndkBuildExt}", '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath, 'clean'
}

tasks.withType(Delete) {
    cleanTask -> cleanTask.dependsOn ndkClean
}
```

I have also further modified `Android.mk` files for the executables so the final executables end up in `assets/<target_arch_abi>/<executable`.

```
SAVED_NDK_APP_DST_DIR := $(NDK_APP_DST_DIR)
NDK_APP_DST_DIR := assets/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
...LOCAL_MODULE/LOCAL_CFLAGS/LOCAL_etc...
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
NDK_APP_DST_DIR := $(SAVED_NDK_APP_DST_DIR)
```

now, running `gradlew build` builds the executables alongside the rest.

Hope this helps.